# CMS: How to handle internal URLs best?

Tags: php, database, url, replace

I think about what might be the best way handling internal links.

At the moment I just paste the full URL in the WYSIWYG-editor and replace it with an placeholder before the content gets inserted into the database.

```
ROOT_URL = "http://localhost/projectname/";
$content = Helper::replace_all(ROOT_URL, "{{{ROOT_URL}}}", $content); // custom
```

Before outputting the content, the placeholder gets replaced by the current ROOT_URL.

```
$content = Helper::replace_all("{{{ROOT_URL}}}", ROOT_URL, $content); // custom
```

It works fine, but I'd like to know your best practices. How would you handle this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Great idea to anticipate the renaming of absolute url! +1

Comment: Nice approach for WYSIWYG. I used the same in my custom CMS. Users are too lazy to handle URLS correctly and just copy/paste them from browser address bar. And you can easily migrate your site to the different domain name.

Comment: Depends on how your WYSIWYG editor is set up. What happens if the URL of the page the user is linking to changes? What happens if the website’s domain changes? There’s a lot of different factors that would determine the solution you employ.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options from the top of my head:

- You can build a custom link picker for your wysiwyg editor which will use the `ROOT_URL` and insert it directly into the wysiwyg editor. (We do this at the company I work at)
- You can use relative urls everywhere and output your `ROOT_URL` into a `<base>` tag on your website. (This technique is a bit controversial, but personally I like it very much)
- You can set up your HOSTS file on development to use an actual domain name (thus more similar to the production environment) and make all paths simply absolute. Not as versatile as the solution above, but more widely accepted.
- Use a placeholder like you are doing now.

Personally I think the best solution is definitely the first one, because the second, third and fourth solutions require the user to comprehend the way links are build. The huge disadvantage of the first solution is that when the domain changes you have hardcoded links in your content. Alternatively you can also have the custom link picker insert a placeholder, this could probably be even better. (And keep the rest the same). The second and third solutions are probably the simplest to integrate and use practically.

Comment: Both the link picker and the placeholder are great solutions. The risk with link picker is the copy/pasting directly in the wysiwyg of links inside that cms. Maybe doing both of them would be perfect ;)